# EKS loadbalancer created successfully with external ip but web app is unreachable on assigned port

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am learning k8s with eksctl and used this to create a loadbalancer:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

it was created ok and `kubectl get service/lb` lists it as well a long aws domain name representing the external IP (let's call this `<awsdomain>`).

I then deployed my app:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: <account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/myapp:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

I did `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` and that also seems to have worked. However, when I go to my browser, `http://<awsdomain>:3000` doesn't return anything :(

Is there another resource I'm supposed to create? Thanks.

Comment: Your service definition says to route traffic to pods with the label `app: lb` but your deployment does not match that selector.

Comment: @jordanm that was it!!  I was just blindly using labels, forgetting that they are used as selectors. It works now!!! If you want to add your comment as an official answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service selector will not select any pod. Try:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: myapp    # <-- change to match the pod template
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try port 80 instead of 3000. Those ports you set are for the K, not for AWS infrastructure. AWS LB is on port 80.

Use "k get svc" and it should give you the external address which it should be available. And It must be on port 80.

Comment: Listener ports on AWS ELBs can be configured to other ports.

Comment: Yes, I know that but needs to be configured. Port 80 is the one that is opened by default. The others need to be opened manually and OP doesn't know about it.